# Hypernyms for restaurant dishes

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, hypernyms

Suppose I classify dishes in a restaurant menu. I would like to classify them by two categories:

- *Category 1*:

  1. entree
  2. main course
  3. dessert
  4. etc.
- *Category 2*:

  1. meat
  2. fish
  3. vegetables
  4. cheese
  5. etc.

What would you call *category 1* and *category 2* ?

Comment: Perhaps simply by _course type_ and _content type_? Though I'll admit these sound a bit like variables in a script, rather than actual, useful describers.

Comment: As you suggest, the first category is course/s. The second? 'Food category'!? Do you really need to have category labels? And if your 'etc' goes with 'cheeses' rather than '4', 'cereals/carbs' and 'fruit' are missing.

Comment: Related: What is the hypernym/category for restaurant dishes that includes: *plates, platters, saucers, bowls, trays, porringers, salvers, mugs, pitchers, casseroles, tankards, tureens, carafes, urns* and the like?

Comment: In the US, the main course is often called the *entrée*, just to confuse Europeans

Answer (score 5):

The first group can be called *[courses](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/course?)*

> a part of a meal served at one time:  *the fish course*

The second category can be called *[ingredients](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ingredients?)*

> a component of a mixture, compound, etc, esp. in cooking

If you want to be more precise, you could say *main ingredients*.

Comment: *[Foodstuffs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foodstuff#Noun)* might serve slightly better than *ingredients*

Comment: @jwpat7 While I don't disagree that *foodstuffs* might work, *ingredients* is the standard term used in recipes. I guess it depends on where OP will use it and how offbeat/mainstream he wants to be.

Comment: *Foodstuffs* is a better hypernym for the listed items: it's more precise and more limiting than *ingredients*.  There are recipes for all sorts of things besides food, and all kinds of ingredients that have nothing to do with food.  But I agree *ingredients* might serve the desired purpose.